# PrestoDB Hive Catalog: no viable alternative at input 'CREATE EXTERNAL'

Tags: hive, parquet, presto

I am running a query in Teradata PrestoDB distribution  for Hive `catalog` as:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive.default.mydata
id INT, datetime timestamp, latitude FLOAT,
longitude FLOAT, bookingid VARCHAR, pre_lat FLOAT,
pre_long FLOAT, time_hour decimal(6, 1), dist_kms decimal(6, 1),
ma6_dist_kms decimal(6, 1), istationary INT, quality_overall VARCHAR,
quality_nonstationary VARCHAR, cartype VARCHAR, isbigloss INT,
bookregion VARCHAR, iho_road VARCHAR)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION "s3://sb.mycompany.com/someFolder/anotherFolder";
```

Throwing following exception:

```
Query 20180316_022346_00001_h9iie failed: line 1:8: no viable alternative at input 'CREATE EXTERNAL'
```

Even when I use hive and run a show table command, I see an error as **Schema is set but catalog is not**:

```
presto> use hive;
presto:hive> show tables;
Error running command:
Error starting query at http://localhost:8080/v1/statement returned HTTP response code 400.
Response info:
JsonResponse{statusCode=400, statusMessage=Bad Request, headers={Content-Length=[32], Date=[Fri, 16 Mar 2018 02:25:25 GMT], Content-Type=[text/plain]}, hasValue=false, value=null}
Response body:
Schema is set but catalog is not
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing like `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` in Presto. In order to create Hive external table in Presto, please do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE hive.web.request_logs (
  request_time timestamp,
  url varchar,
  ip varchar,
  user_agent varchar
)
WITH (
  format = 'TEXTFILE',
  external_location = 's3://my-bucket/data/logs/'
)
```

Please visit this page to see how to interact with Hive from Presto: https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/connector/hive.html?highlight=hive

`use hive;` set only the current schema in the user session. I think you wanted to do something like: `USE hive.default;`. Please take a look here for more details: https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/sql/use.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for this guidance and resource you pointed out to, that really helps me. The query is working fine now.

Comment: Why am i seeing this error in v307?
io.prestosql.spi.PrestoException: External tables cannot be created using CREATE TABLE AS
 at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.HiveMetadata.beginCreateTable(HiveMetadata.java:1035)
 at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.HiveMetadata.beginCreateTable(HiveMetadata.java:220)